Temporal: unable to find workflow type: Supported types: []
[Solved]:
Looks like I needed to create and run a worker on the client side to have the workflow DummyActivity registered with Temporal.
=====
I'm getting started with Temporal and would like some help understanding the concepts. I've followed the tutorial on the temporal.io website and successfully completed the money transfer tutorial. Now, I'm working on a use case involving two services:

A server in Golang that implements individual activities and registers them with Temporal.
A client in TypeScript that defines the workflow specifying how these tasks should be run.

I've set up the Temporal server, and both services point to the same task queue. While the client does not implement the activities, it does have their definitions. However, when running the client and checking the status of the workflow on the Temporal UI page, I get this error: WORKFLOW_TASK_FAILED_CAUSE_WORKFLOW_WORKER_UNHANDLED_FAILURE.
Can anyone provide guidance on what might be causing this error or how to resolve it?
Here is the Golang code (server side) where I create the worker and execute the activities:
main.go
package main

import (
    "log"

    "go.temporal.io/sdk/client"
    "go.temporal.io/sdk/worker"
)

func main() {

    // Create Temporal client
    c, err := client.Dial(client.Options{
        HostPort:  "localhost:7233",
        Namespace: "default",
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Unable to create Temporal client", err)
    }
    defer c.Close()

    // Create a Temporal worker
    w := worker.New(c, "operation-queue", worker.Options{})

    // Register activities
    w.RegisterActivity(DummyActivity1)
    w.RegisterActivity(DummyActivity2)

    // Start worker
    err = w.Run(worker.InterruptCh())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Unable to start Worker", err)
    }
}

activities.go
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
)

func DummyActivity1(ctx context.Context, input string) (string, error) {
    log.Println("Executing DummyActivity1 with input:", input)
    return input + " output1", nil
}

func DummyActivity2(ctx context.Context, input string) (string, error) {
    log.Println("Executing DummyActivity2 with input:", input)
    return input + " output2", nil`
}

Now for the Typescript code (client side).  I have all code in one file for simplicity:
client.ts
import { Connection, WorkflowClient } from '@temporalio/client';
import { proxyActivities } from '@temporalio/workflow';
import { ApplicationFailure } from '@temporalio/common';

export interface Activities {
  DummyActivity1: (input: string) => Promise<string>;
  DummyActivity2: (input: string) => Promise<string>;
}

const { DummyActivity1 } = proxyActivities<Activities>({
  startToCloseTimeout: '1 minute',
  retry: {
      initialInterval: 1000,
      maximumInterval: 60,
      backoffCoefficient: 2,
      maximumAttempts: 500
  },
})

export async function DummyActivity(input: string): Promise<string> {

  console.log(`starting to execute workflow`)

  let result: string;
  try {
    result = await DummyActivity1(input);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`failed to call service`)
    throw new ApplicationFailure(`Error: ${err}`);
  }

  return `result ${result}`;
  
}

async function run() {

  const namespace = "default"
  const connection = await Connection.connect();
  const client = new WorkflowClient({ connection, namespace });

  console.log(
     `Starting workflow`
  );

  const handle = await client.start(DummyActivity, {
    args: ["input"],
    taskQueue: 'operation-queue',
    workflowId: 'dummy-activity',
  });

  console.log(
    `Started Workflow ${handle.workflowId} with RunID ${handle.firstExecutionRunId}`
  );
  console.log(await handle.result());
}

run().catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
  process.exit(1);
});

Here is a screenshot of the error from the localhost Temporal UI:
screenshot of the error from the localhost Temporal UI(https://i.sstatic.net/3Kykuosl.png)
Thank you for your help
I expected the client to trigger the workflow and for the activities to be executed by the Go server without any issues. I have verified that the worker is registered with Temporal and that the task queue is set up properly.
